# Problems with node names in Igraph with R

Tags: igraph, names, vertices

I have a list of data.frames (dfList) from which I'd like to generate directed weighted networks in Igraph in R.
The edge-weight variable is "ValueUSD", while vertices are identified by numbers with the columns "Reporter" and "Partner".
Here it follows a function I prepared called "write.graphs" to be used with lapply on my "dfList".

```
write.graphs<-function(filename){
  d<-graph.data.frame(filename[c("Reporter", "Partner")], directed=TRUE)
  d <- set.edge.attribute(d, "weight", value=filename$ValueUSD)
}
graphs<-lapply(dfList, write.graphs)
```

Every thing work perfectly. If I check for vertex names I get:

```
graphs[1]$names
NULL
```

But troubles emerge when I want to use names in place of numbers to identify my vertices, using the corresponding  columns "ReporterN" and "PartnerN" in each of my data.frames in dfLIst.
Here you can see how my data.frames look like:

```
dfList[1]
$`Aug 2014`
    Reporter YearPeriod Year Period Commodity Partner NetWeightKg ValueUSD    Price             PartnerN      ReporterN
1         76     201408 2014      8    150910       0     4472917 22028271  4.924811                World         Brazil
2         76     201408 2014      8    150910      32      380891  1533948  4.027262            Argentina         Brazil
3         76     201408 2014      8    150910     152      239776  1336057  5.572105                Chile         Brazil
4         76     201408 2014      8    150910     251         289     2164  7.487889               France         Brazil
5         76     201408 2014      8    150910     300       27592   170658  6.185054               Greece         Brazil
6
```

This is the message I get:

```
> grafi<-lapply(dfList, scrivi.grafi)
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In graph.data.frame(filename[c("ReporterN", "PartnerN")],  ... :
  In `d' `NA' elements were replaced with string "NA"
2: In graph.data.frame(filename[c("ReporterN", "PartnerN")],  ... :
  In `d' `NA' elements were replaced with string "NA"
3: In graph.data.frame(filename[c("ReporterN", "PartnerN")],  ... :
```

If it helps, I checked:

```
class(dfList[1]$PartnerN)
[1] "NULL"
```

Any suggestion? Can anyone explain me what happens?

Thanks a lot, Umberto.

Comment: Use `graphs[1]$name`, not `graphs[1]$names` since the names are stored in the `name` vertex attribute.

Comment: Thanks @Tamás, but the problem is not with [graph[1]$names]. Anyway, I tried graph[1]$name and I get a NULL result. The problem is with substituting [c("Reporter", "Partner")] with [c("ReporterN", "PartnerN")]: once I do this, I cannot get the graphs since I get: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In graph.data.frame(filename[c("ReporterN", "PartnerN")],  ... :
...    Any suggestion?